# Trying to run an HTA gives "This app can't run on your PC"

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a number of [HTA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536495(v=vs.85).aspx)s on my computer.

Now when I try to run them, I get the message:

> This app can't run on your PC.
>
> To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher.

Even a simple HTML file, renamed to the `.hta` extension, has the same problem.

When I try **Open With** in the context menu, the `mshta.exe` executable no longer appears in the context menu (like it used to). When I browse to it (either the 32-bit or 64-bit version) I get the following:

> The program you have selected cannot be associated with this file type. Please choose another program.

I get the same message whether or not I've checked the **Always use this app to open '.hta' files** checkbox.

When I try calling `mhsta.exe` from the command line and passing in the name of the HTA as an argument, the HTA doesn't open, but there are no additional errors.

Are HTAs now deprecated / disabled? How can I resolve this?

I am running:

> Windows 10 Pro
> Version 1709
> OS Build 16299.431
> 64-bit architecture and OS

Comment: Same Version but Build 16299.371 and no Problem with `.hta` files

Comment: works on my win10 , and im on latest april spring update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the following two commands as administrator:

- Add file type with [`ftype`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftype) command:

```
ftype htafile=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshta.exe "%1" {1E460BD7-F1C3-4B2E-88BF-4E770A288AF5}%U{1E460BD7-F1C3-4B2E-88BF-4E770A288AF5} %*
```

- Associate `.hta` extension with [`assoc`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/assoc) command:

```
assoc .hta=htafile
```

Then sign out and re-sign in to your account.

Comment: Is there any benefit to doing this over direct registry manipulation?

Comment: This command is copied from latest Windows. And you've to run just two commands.

Comment: Yes. If there are no better answers I will award the bounty here.

Answer (score 2):

Try to see if your antivirus product has decided that .hta applications are
a security threat (which they are, allowing an html file to modify the system).

If you need to reestablish the registry settings for .hta applications,
you may create and execute a .reg file containing the following text.
The contents are a modification of the github file
[Default_HTA.reg](https://github.com/bmrf/tron/blob/master/resources/stage_4_repair/repair_file_extensions/Default_HTA.reg)
with data from my computer :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.hta]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.hta]
"PerceivedType"="text"
@="htafile"
"Content Type"="application/hta"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.hta\PersistentHandler]
@="{eec97550-47a9-11cf-b952-00aa0051fe20}"

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htafile]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htafile]
"EditFlags"=dword:00100000
@="HTML Application"
"FriendlyTypeName"="@C:\\Windows\\System32\\mshta.exe,-6412"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htafile\CLSID]
@="{3050f4d8-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htafile\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\mshta.exe,1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htafile\Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htafile\Shell\Open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htafile\Shell\Open\Command]
@="C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\mshta.exe \"%1\" %*"

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.hta]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.hta]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.hta]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.hta\OpenWithList]
"a"="IEXPLORE.EXE"
"MRUList"="a"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.hta\OpenWithProgids]
"htafile"=hex(0):
```

Please note that the above text of
`C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\mshta.exe` relates to 32-bit execution.
For 64-bit execution use instead `C:\\Windows\\System32\\mshta.exe`.

As further note, please create a system restore point before doing any
registry changes, just in case.

Comment: I am using Avira Free antivirus. There doesn't seem to be any explicit option to disable HTAs, nor did I find any settings that seem to be related.

Comment: that was a really PERFECT answer, how did you know those changes on the registry?